# Navigation on double tap on tabs in UITabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using https://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController  And i want to navigate on poptorootviewcontroller on double tap on tabbar items.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: May be i am not that much mature to understand the problem. You are right at your side. I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Add a gesture recognize on the tabbar.

Get the touch position and see what tab was intended to be touched and pop to root view controller.

Comment: I need another way. Thank for reply

Comment: Terente : Thanks for your wishes. I had already way to do it.

[btnMyCard addTarget:self action:@selector(myCardButtontappedtwice) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];